Area of a Quater-Circle with hyperbolic elements
The actual question states the following;
"Find the mass of a Quater-Disc (in terms of R), in the first quadrant, of radius 'R' if density varies as D = xy"
My first thought was somehow turning this problem into another one in hyperbolic coordinates and integrating for the transformation of a circle there with density varying radially, but then I realised I can't do that because I don't know how to.
I also thought about taking hyperbolic elements and the density function as xy=k where k goes from 0 to R/2 but I just couldn't figure out how to take elements that don't have an anchor for me to keep constant.
I can visually grasp the problem statement and its intention but I fail to materialize it into equations I can evaluate..
Any help is appreciated.

Given the density function $D = xy$ and the quarter-disc in the first quadrant with radius $R$, we'll set up the integral to find the mass.$$\\$$Okay so mainly you can do that in 4 steps that you're gonna read right now, try to do that on your own for your own good
The first step: Parameterization:

Let $x$ vary from $0$ to $R$ and $y$ vary from $0$ to $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ to describe the quarter-disc in the first quadrant.

The second step: Density Function:

$D = xy$.

The third step: Setting Up the Integral:

The mass ($M$) is given by the double integral over the quarter-disc:
$$ M = \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}} xy \, dy \, dx $$

The fourth step: Evaluating the Integral:

First, integrate with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$, then integrate the result with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $R$.

Let's start by integrating $xy$ with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$:
$$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}} xy \, dy = x \cdot \left[ \frac{1}{2}y^2 \right]_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}} = x \cdot \frac{1}{2} (R^2 - x^2) $$
Now, integrate this expression with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $R$:
$$ M = \int_{0}^{R} x \cdot \frac{1}{2} (R^2 - x^2) \, dx $$
$$ M = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{R} (R^2x - x^3) \, dx $$
$$ M = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{2} R^2x^2 - \frac{1}{4} x^4 \right]_{0}^{R} $$
$$ M = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} R^2 \cdot R^2 - \frac{1}{4} R^4 \right) $$
$$ M = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2} R^4 - \frac{1}{4} R^4 \right) $$
$$ M = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} R^4 $$
$$ M = \frac{1}{8} R^4 $$
So, the mass of the quarter-disc in terms of $R$ is $ \frac{1}{8} R^4 $.

You could also set it up in polar coordinates $$M = \iint_Q D, rd\theta,dr =\int_0^Rr^3\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta\sin\theta,d\theta,dr=\frac 12\int_0^Rr^3,dr\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin 2\theta,d\theta$$
